# AuthenticationException: errors.authentication.USG_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED

Tags: sabre

The following is the request which I sent as part of SessionCreateRQ to https://sws3-crt.cert.sabre.com. But I received

> AuthenticationException:
>   errors.authentication.USG_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED

response. I couldn't find IPCC in my profile. So I mentioned 'IPCC' in *Organization* tag. Should the *Organization* tag contain the correct IPCC to get authenticated?

**Note:** I have replaced my actual username and password with 'xxxxxxxxxx' and 'yyyyyyyyyy' respectively.

**Request:**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" eb:version="1.0">
            <eb:ConversationId>support@sabre.com</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">999999</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">123123</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:CPAId>IPCC</eb:CPAId>
            <eb:Service eb:type="OTA">SessionCreateRQ</eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>SessionCreateRQ</eb:Action>
            <eb:MessageData>
                <eb:MessageId>1000</eb:MessageId>
                <eb:Timestamp>2016-10-18T14:35:19Z</eb:Timestamp>
                <eb:TimeToLive>2016-10-18T14:35:19Z</eb:TimeToLive>
            </eb:MessageData>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/utility">
            <wsse:UsernameToken> 
                <wsse:Username>xxxxxxxxxx</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password>yyyyyyyyyy</wsse:Password>
                <Organization>IPCC</Organization>
                <Domain>DEFAULT</Domain> 
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <eb:Manifest SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" eb:version="1.0">
            <eb:Reference xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="cid:rootelement" xlink:type="simple"/>
        </eb:Manifest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**Response:**

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap-env:Header>
      <eb:MessageHeader eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
         <eb:From>
            <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">123123</eb:PartyId>
         </eb:From>
         <eb:To>
            <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">999999</eb:PartyId>
         </eb:To>
         <eb:CPAId>IPCC</eb:CPAId>
         <eb:ConversationId>support@sabre.com</eb:ConversationId>
         <eb:Service eb:type="OTA">SessionCreateRQ</eb:Service>
         <eb:Action>ErrorRS</eb:Action>
         <eb:MessageData>
            <eb:MessageId>2900801526094550610</eb:MessageId>
            <eb:Timestamp>2016-10-18T14:36:49</eb:Timestamp>
            <eb:RefToMessageId>1000</eb:RefToMessageId>
         </eb:MessageData>
      </eb:MessageHeader>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"/>
   </soap-env:Header>
   <soap-env:Body>
      <soap-env:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap-env:Client.AuthenticationFailed</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Authentication failed</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <StackTrace>com.sabre.universalservices.base.security.AuthenticationException: errors.authentication.USG_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED</StackTrace>
         </detail>
      </soap-env:Fault>
   </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

Having an IPCC is mandatory in order to create a session thru SOAP.

I'm guessing you currently have the test credentials granted to you when creating an account on DevStudio, which will only allow you to test on CERT with REST API.

Answer (score 0):

When you register to Dev Studio, you only get access to REST APIs in the test environment.

In order to access SOAP APIs, you can contact do that via: https://developer.sabre.com/contact or webservices.support@sabre.com