# Not able access SOAP API Access Token

Tags: sabre

I am Implementing SOAP API in my online travel system, I am trying to get **SOAP API Access Token** using **curl request**.

I have followed this article https://developer.sabre.com/resources/getting_started_with_sabre_apis/how_to_get_a_token#3sub4 to get SOAP API Access Token using my **PCC number** **"s6ci"** but when I run that code I am getting empty response.

Can you please check and let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Below is the code which I have used using soap api.

```
$environment = 'https://api.test.sabre.com';
// request string
$request = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema">
<soap-env:Header>
<eb:MessageHeader soap-env:mustUnderstand="1" eb:version="1.0">
<eb:From>
<eb:PartyId />
</eb:From>
<eb:To>
<eb:PartyId />
</eb:To>
<eb:CPAId>s6ci</eb:CPAId>
<eb:ConversationId>V1@280b16ec-5eac-46c0-893f-c88f8e8cb632@310b16ec-5dad-46c0-893f-c88f8e8cb643@780b16ec-5eac-46c0-893f-c88f8e8cb699</eb:ConversationId>
<eb:Service>SessionCreateRQ</eb:Service>
<eb:Action>SessionCreateRQ</eb:Action>
<eb:MessageData />
</eb:MessageHeader>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/utility">
<wsse:UsernameToken>
<wsse:Username>MyUsername</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password>MyPassword</wsse:Password>
<Organization>s6ci</Organization>
<Domain />
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</soap-env:Header>
<soap-env:Body>
<eb:Manifest soap-env:mustUnderstand="1" eb:version="1.0">
<eb:Reference xlink:href="cid:rootelement" xlink:type="simple" />
</eb:Manifest>
<SessionCreateRQ>
<POS>
<Source PseudoCityCode="s6ci" />
</POS>
</SessionCreateRQ>
<ns:SessionCreateRQ xmlns:ns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2002/11" />
</soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
';
//initialize curl request
$ch = curl_init($environment);
$headers = array(
'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',
'Accept: text/xml',
"Content-Length: " . strlen($request)
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// print response
echo 'Token '.$result;
exit;
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($result);

curl_close($ch);

return json_decode($result);
```

Awaiting for your response.

Thank you.
Amy T

Answer (score 0):

Could not get a response with your code either somehow. I pasted you my working code. Please replace the XXXX (its according to how many chars there are any where they are comming from/what they are)

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <eb:MessageHeader SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" eb:version="1.0">
         <eb:From>
            <eb:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">999999</eb:PartyId>
         </eb:From>
         <eb:To>
            <eb:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">123123</eb:PartyId>
         </eb:To>
         <eb:CPAId>XXXX(PCC)</eb:CPAId>
         <eb:ConversationId>SWS-Test-Y8BI</eb:ConversationId>
         <eb:Service eb:type="OTA">SessionCreateRQ</eb:Service>
         <eb:Action>SessionCreateRQ</eb:Action>
         <eb:MessageData>
            <eb:MessageId>1000</eb:MessageId>
            <eb:Timestamp>2012-06-07T10:00:00</eb:Timestamp>
            <eb:TimeToLive>2013-06-06T23:59:59</eb:TimeToLive>
         </eb:MessageData>
      </eb:MessageHeader>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/utility">
         <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>XXXXXX(Uname)</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>XXXXXXXX(PW)</wsse:Password>
            <Organization>XXXX(PCC)</Organization>
            <Domain>DEFAULT</Domain>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SessionCreateRQ>
         <POS>
            <Source PseudoCityCode="XXXX(PCC)"/>
         </POS>
      </SessionCreateRQ>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but it's not working for me. I have read this article may be this is the issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/40113153/9585845

Answer (score 0):

You are correct you did.  Below is a working code segment.  I just logged into Sabre using this in Postman.

```html
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema">
  <soap-env:Header>
    <eb:MessageHeader soap-env:mustUnderstand="1" eb:version="1.0">
      <eb:From>
        <eb:PartyId/>
      </eb:From>
      <eb:To>
        <eb:PartyId/>
      </eb:To>
      <eb:CPAId>XXXX(PCC)</eb:CPAId>
      <eb:ConversationId>SWS-Test-Y8BI</eb:ConversationId>
      <eb:Service>SessionCreateRQ</eb:Service>
      <eb:Action>SessionCreateRQ</eb:Action>
      <eb:MessageData>
        <eb:MessageId>mid:20001209-133003-2333@clientofsabre.com</eb:MessageId>
        <eb:Timestamp>2018-04-04T022:58:31Z</eb:Timestamp>
      </eb:MessageData>
    </eb:MessageHeader>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/utility">
      <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>XXXXXX(Uname)</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password>XXXXXXXX(PW)</wsse:Password>
        <Organization>XXXX(PCC)</Organization>
        <Domain>DEFAULT</Domain>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap-env:Header>
  <soap-env:Body>
    <eb:Manifest soap-env:mustUnderstand="1" eb:version="1.0">
      <eb:Reference xlink:href="cid:rootelement" xlink:type="simple" />
    </eb:Manifest>
    <SessionCreateRQ>
      <POS>
        <Source PseudoCityCode="XXXX(PCC)" />
      </POS>
    </SessionCreateRQ>
    <ns:SessionCreateRQ xmlns:ns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2002/11" />
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

In your example, you are missing under MessageData the MessageID and the Timestamp.  In Domain you are entering you PCC again.  That should be "DEFAULT".  When I took these elements out of my example it stopped working so I am assuming that this is your issue as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have already <eb:Action>SessionCreateRQ</eb:Action> in my soap request header.